# Sign into session as preexisting_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, session, omniauth

I'm getting the error: "couldn't find user with id" when trying to sign in with facebook. I want it where if a user is had already been created it triggers the first set of code in the conditional and if the user is new it triggers the second set of code:

**sessions_controller**

```
  def facebook
    preexisting_user = User.find(params[:id]) # What should go in this line?
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    if preexisting_user
      cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url
      flash.now[:info] = 'Welcome Back to Live to Challenge!'
    else
      action = session.delete(:challenge_action)
      user.challenges.create(action: action)
      user.send_welcome_email
      user.remember
      cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to tutorial_url
      flash.now[:info] = 'Welcome to Live to Challenge!'
    end
  end
```

**user.rb**

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     # Sets 60 day auth token
     oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("154037ewr2976229929", "ee917abf2ere8f1c98274cdfwqreaebb1346f4")
     new_access_info = oauth.exchange_access_token_info auth.credentials.token

     new_access_token = new_access_info["access_token"]
     new_access_expires_at = DateTime.now + new_access_info["expires"].to_i.seconds

    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = new_access_token # auth.credentials.token <- your old token. Not needed anymore.
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.password = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
      user.email = SecureRandom.hex + "@mailinator.com" unless user.email.present?
      user.activated = true
      user.save!
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code, i am sure it will work.

```
def facebook
  user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  # preexisting_user = User.find(params[:id]) # What should go in this line?
  # user.persisted? is what you need to add if you want to add here
  # if user pre existed, it will execute if block otherwise else block.

  # checks if pre-existing user
  if user.persisted?
   cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
   redirect_to root_url
   flash.now[:info] = 'Welcome Back to Live to Challenge!'
  else
   action = session.delete(:challenge_action)
   user.challenges.create(action: action)
   user.send_welcome_email
   user.remember
   cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
   redirect_to tutorial_url
   flash.now[:info] = 'Welcome to Live to Challenge!'
  end
end
```